# Scala- Calculating total time from timestamps for a column value

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

There is a Spark dataframe with a column which gives status and the other column time in ms. I want to know what is the total time for a given state as a new dataframe.

Current dataframe:

```
TimeStamp  Status
120           Running
200           Paused
330           Running
420           Paused
450           Running
600           Stopped
```

Now manually observing the status "Paused" has duration from 200->330 and from 420-> 450.
That is total of 160ms .So the new dataframe would be

```
TotalTime     Status
160            Paused
```

What is the code in Scala to obtain this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may accomplish the following using spark-sql by

1. creating a temporary view of your data eg

```scala
my_df.createOrReplaceTempView("my_table")
```

2. Running the following on your spark session

```scala
result_df = sparkSession.sql("<insert sql below here>")
```

```sql
WITH durations AS (
    SELECT
         Status,
         TimeStamp,
        ((LEAD(TimeStamp,1,TimeStamp) OVER (Order by TimeStamp)) - TimeStamp) as duration
    FROM
        my_table
)
SELECT
   Status,
   SUM(duration) as TotalTime
FROM
   durations
GROUP BY
   Status
```

[Sample Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uLJLDAviN7q35ea37sPi6z/0)